# iAd doesn't fit width when starts from landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, iad

I am switching and scaling properly iAd on portraid and landscape mode excepts when view starts from landscape mode. In this case, iAd remains at narrow width that corresponds to portraid. Then when rotate the device to portraid and back to landscape, is solved. How to solve it? Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    //iAd

    adView =[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];

    adView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:adView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not tell the adView with which orientation to start, so it starts with the default orientation.

Try adding the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
} else {
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
}
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

Comment: Now when starts in landscape mode fits properly but when starts with portrait fits like landscape!

Comment: EDIT: if I change if and else content, so ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait to Landscape and reverse, it works! but I do not understand at all, should work as you suggested, isn't it?

Comment: It works fine until iOS6 where all these property becomes deprecated.  Now the problem raise over again.